# I cannot get OnSeekBarChangeListener to work in Android code

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use OOP in my Java/Android code, but I don't understand why `OnSeekBarChangeListener` is not working in my new class.
Is it prohibited to use a `OnSeekBarChangeListener` outside main activity?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    timescroller = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    TimeScroller Tm = new TimeScroller();

    Tm.mp = mp;
    Tm.ts = timescroller;
    Tm.mTimeScroller();

    timescroller.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            if(b){
                mp.seekTo(i);
            }
        }
            @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mp.setVolume(0,0);
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mp.setVolume(1,1);
        }
    });
}
```

---

And here is my class

```
package com.phillipvm.gridlayout;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class TimeScroller {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    SeekBar ts;
    public void mTimeScroller(MediaPlayer _mp,SeekBar _ts){
        mp =_mp;
        ts = _ts;
        ts.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                if(b){
                    mp.seekTo(i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                mp.setVolume(0,0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                mp.setVolume(1,1);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your TimeScroller class has no constructor, and it is unclear when the mTimeScroller method would be called. Probably never - that's why it's not working. Also, please take care to give your questions clear, understandable titles and descriptions. If you want the community to help you, the least you can do is save everyone time by expressing yourself clearly.

Answer (score 0):

i can't see the code where you are using the class! 
you are calling Tm.mTimeScroller(); but in your class the method takes 2 parameters !